# React native onStartShouldSetResponder parameter not working for AutoCompeletInput plugin

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am using plugin for Autocomplete Input. ***I have placed this component in Scrollview.*** It's other behaviour is fine like displaying suggestion list in popup with our custom design.

Referred Plugin:- [Plugin](https://github.com/l-urence/react-native-autocomplete-input)

But **onStartShouldSetResponder{()=>true} not working**. 
Because of that I am unable to scroll my suggestion list.

Here is my implemented code =>

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' style={[commonstyles.mainContainer,styles.mainContainer,{marginBottom:20}]}>
            <View style={{width:width-30,height:45}}>
            <Autocomplete
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              hideResults={false}
              containerStyle={{flex: 1,left: 10,position: 'absolute',right: 10,top: 0,zIndex: 1}}
              data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].name) ? [] : films}
              defaultValue={query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
              placeholder="Select Contact"
              renderItem={({ id,name }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onStartShouldSetResponder={()=>{return true;}} activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name })}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:Global.DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE,color:Global.APP_BLACK_COLOR,borderBottomWidth:0.5,borderColor:Global.APP_BLACK_COLOR,padding:5}}>
                    {id} {name}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            />
            </View>

</Scrollview>
```

- Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.
- Also I am unable to understand implementation of onStartShouldSetResponder() function.
- Suggest Autocomplete input example in react native which work like Android AutoCompleteTexview component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **scrollEnabled** parameter to your Scrollview.

Try with below code

```
<ScrollView scrollEnabled={this.state.enableScrollViewScroll} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' style={[commonstyles.mainContainer,styles.mainContainer,{marginBottom:20}]}>
    <View style={{width:width-30,height:45}}>
    <Autocomplete
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      hideResults={false}
      onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
         var self=this;
         this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: false });
         console.log("Here==>",self.state.enableScrollViewScroll);
      }}
      containerStyle={{flex: 1,left: 10,position: 'absolute',right: 10,top: 0,zIndex: 1}}
      data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].name) ? [] : films}
      defaultValue={query}
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
      placeholder="Select Contact"
      renderItem={({ id,name }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity  activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name,enableScrollViewScroll:true })}>
          <Text style=                {{fontSize:Global.DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE,color:Global.APP_BLACK_COLOR,borderBottomWidth:0.5,borderColor:Global.APP_BLACK_COLOR,padding:5}}>
        {id} {name}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
    </View>

</Scrollview>
```